# Custom data contract serializer for faults

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract, fault

Is there a way to replace the default data contract serializer for faults?

A custom data contract serializer can be attached by replacing the default `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior` on each operation. But this doesn't serializes/deserializes faults...

Comment: Somewhat of a late comment, but maybe you'll find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20797843/389966) useful.